# Nuxt.js 3 load binary file from server

Tags: server, nuxt.js, fs, nuxtjs3

I want to get the contents of a binary file from an api endpoint (`/server/api/xxx.ts`) in Nuxt.js 3.

I noticed that having the binary file under the server directory, for example `/server/files/file.bin`, it doesn't get bundled on build.

I believe that using hooks in the config file, somewhat similarly to the example in the [docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config#hooks), it can be done (didn't try yet). But it seems over-complicating.

Is there a "best practice" for something like this?

Of course it's possible to make that file available in `/public/files/file.bin` and fetch it from the address like `http://localhost:3000/files/file.bin`, and although in my case the file can be public, it seems not to be a desirable solution.